# jquery .slideToggle on .click inside a div filled with .post data

Tags: jquery, html

i have a div with the id  #1
i fill this div #1 with .post data (html output from php).
the received data contains multiple divs with classes .2 and .3 i want to do the slideToggle on .3 when .2 is clicked. 
since the #1 div is filled multiple times( with `$('#1').append(data)` ) i have multiple .2 and .3 to apply the toggle on.
ive searched a while and found out that i can use delegated event listeners.
i think with this method it will piling up listeners after every AJAX call since im not targetting only the new elements but all of the previous ones as well.(i hope so)
but its not working. i use this code:

lets say the html looks like this before the ajax call
`<div id="1"></div>`
and after the ajax call its filled like so:

```
<div id="1">
   <div class="2">Click me<div>
   <div class="3">Im the toggled content</div>
   <div class="2">Click me too<div>
   <div class="3">Im the toggled content too</div>
</div>
```

and now i want to apply this jquery on the received content:

```
$('#1').on('click', '.2', function () {
    $('.3').slideToggle('slow');
});
```

but its not working :/ why?

ive adaptet the code from the answer on this question: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38597753/slidetoggle-wont-work-on-ajax-rendered-content)

i think the body element from this code is equivalent with the #1 div in my code since i append data to it(and he adds data to the body element). but nothing happens when i click :/

thanks in advance
what im doing wrong?

Comment: if you load that up in a jsfiddle it works https://jsfiddle.net/g51qvnha/ , can you post the rest of your code?

Comment: I have solved it: I had the function .on over the div #1 which was filled. If I move this function under the div #1 then it works - the devil is in the detail.

Answer (score 2):

Your divs are not closed properly

change it to

```
<div id="1">
   <div class="2">Click me</div>
   <div class="3">Im the toggled content</div>
   <div class="2">Click me too</div>
   <div class="3">Im the toggled content too</div>
</div>
```

then you can do something like this

```
$('#1').on('click','.2', function () {
    $(this).next('.3').slideToggle('slow');
});
```

here is a working fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/g51qvnha/2/

Comment: oh that was only a typo by tipping too fast the question here :P but thanks for your answer.  the  `$(this).next()` function is verry good, thats what im searched for after solving the problem in the question because i dont want to souround the .2 div the .3 div :) because then the .3 div become clickable when its visible :) thanks